# Dynamic form validation in symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

Before receiving `$_POST` information from form submission, I didn't know anything about the number of fields, types or validation rules (whether the field is required, whether it should be a valid email, etc.)

In ohter words, the validation rules and fields depend on what i receive in `$_POST`:
user creates form fields and defines validation rules by himself.

So I need to set validation rules after I'll receive `$_POST`

What will be most right method to do this in symfony2?

Comment: Do you mean the validation rules and fields depend on what you receive in `$_POST`? If yes you should probably clarify this in your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i mean that. Question edited.

Comment: You didn't draw the problem with too many details. It might be that validation groups would solve it. With more complex rules you might implement your validation rules in custom validators. That depends on what you really want to solve.

Comment: I edited question and added more details to explain what i want. User creates form fields and defines validation rules by himself, then submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

(It seems this paragraph was added not long time ago, or i don't know)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same thing that happens in [CollectionType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CollectionType.php). There the [ResizeFormListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php) instance listens to the `preBind` event to dynamically add or remove fields. You should do the same.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how it can help validate $_POST array dynamically? (without predefined model). There is no problem creating form dynamically. Can you please explain your answer with more details?